JAVA JPA Eager load only first element of sub attribute
Context : i have Auhtor Book and Publisher
public class Author {
    @OneToMany
    List<Book> books;

public class Publisher {
    @OneToMany
    List<Book> books;
}

public class Book {
    @ManyToOne
    Publisher publisher;
}

I'm trying to retrieve authors and only the publisher of their last book without using native query. Is there anyway of eagerly loading only the first element of list<Book> books ?
I found the @EntityGraph that allows me to eagerly load specific attributes of a class, but I didn't find a way to narrow it down to only the first element of a list.

Relationships can be loaded lazily or eagerly, but as far as I am aware, they cannot be loaded partially, which is what you seem to be trying to do.  I think you could get just the author and their last book via a JQL query (so, without a native query), but you cannot get an Author instance whose books attribute has some elements loaded and others not.

In JPA, there­ is no built-in functionality to specify that only the first ele­ment of a collection should be e­agerly loaded.
You can achieve this by using a custom query or by le­veraging the FetchType­.LAZY setting and manually fetching the re­quired data.
